# Mysql Trigger not working. Why?

Tags: mysql, triggers

What i'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Calc` AFTER INSERT on `test`.`bookings` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE `test`.`article` AS `ST`
SET `ST`.`stock` = SUM(`test`.`bookings`.`amount`)
WHERE `ST`.`articlenr` = `test`.`bookings`.`NEW.article`;
END
```

The idea is, to calculate "STOCK" in ARTICLE, after an insert like:

```
Amount: 1 Article: 123
```

on table bookings.

How can this be solved?

Comment: What is *"not working"*?

Comment: MySQL meldet: Dokumentation 
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.article' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE `ST`.`articlenr` = NEW.`article`;
```

New its not a column

```
=(SELECT SUM(`test`.`bookings`.`amount`) FROM `test`.`bookings` GROUP BY article)
```

Comment: Add a group by if you have a aggregate function.

Comment: is the FROM "table" GROUP right?

-

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table GROUP BY `article`) WHERE `ST`.`articlenr` = NEW.`article`; END' at line 4

Comment: Jesus,your table name

Comment: Wich one? bookings or article?

Comment: Thank you :D this works now perfectly :) for delete and update i can use the same or?

Comment: Yeah the deal is the same maybe with minor modifications.Make sure to read more about sql,its not that hard,you need practice.

Comment: I know, i will, but i have to finish a Store-management-System for our Company bevor 1.1.14, that we can use it after new years break.